# How to quit an iteration in OCaml?

Tags: iteration, ocaml

I try to go through a list `xl` by `List.fold_left`, I would like to quit the iteration when some condition is satisfied:

```
List.fold_left
  (fun x acc -> 
     if x = 5 then STOP THE ITERATION
     else x + acc)
xl
```

Could anyone tell me how to express `STOP THE ITERATION` here? Thank you

**Edit1:** By the code above, I would like to say we do not stop accumulation until we meet the first `5`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do this with the built in folds without an exception or some no-op being flagged in the accumulator for the remaining calls --as phimuemue mentions. Alternatively, you can just write a very simple tail-recursive function to take care of returning early,

```
(** Fold left on a list with function [f] until predicate [p] is satisfied **)
let rec fold_until f p acc = function
    | x :: xs when p x -> acc
    | x :: xs -> fold_until f p (f acc x) xs
    | [] -> acc

let accum_until_five =
    fold_until (fun acc x -> x + acc) (fun x -> x = 5) 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Therefore, you'll have to encode the condition into your `x` argument of the inner function:

```
let t l =
    let (a,b) = 
        List.fold_left
            (fun ((accx, condition) as acc) x ->
                if condition then acc else (x+accx, x=5))
            (0,false) l
    in
    a;;
```

That is, you have to tell your function that - once the 5 has been seen - it should simply return the stuff it has done up to now.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods.

Either you add a flag which tells it to stop summing up once a 5 is encountered or you filter the list first or you write your own fold. All three of them are very simple to implement.

Edit: The one posted above with the extra argument is probably the simplest, your own fold is probably the fastest.

You could also use exceptions to escape prematurely, but this more of a hack.

Comment: I don't think exceptions are a hack in this case, or in general, part of the point of local exceptions is this very thing.